# With List of objects how can the `filter` filter know which fields to match on?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I was using filter:query on a json response to filter. Everything worked fine. When I turned the json response into proper classes the filter stopped working. What is the approach to use query to match fields on a class? Is this the situation where I should then create my own custom @NgFilter?

Answer (score 1):

For the AngularDart [`filter` filter](http://ci.angularjs.org/view/Dart/job/angular.dart-master/javadoc/angular.filter/FilterFilter.html) you specify which fields to match on by passing the **field names** as the **keys to a map**.

Let us use the [AngularDart tutorial](https://angulardart.org/tutorial/07-ch05-filter-service.html) `Recipe` class as an example:

```dart
  class Recipe { String id; String name; String category; ... }
```

You can filter, e.g., on `Recipe.name` using the string `ctrl.nameFilterString` write:

```html
  <li ng-repeat="recipe in ctrl.recipes | filter:{name:ctrl.nameFilterString}">
```

Here is an excerpt from the [`filter` API doc](http://ci.angularjs.org/view/Dart/job/angular.dart-master/javadoc/angular.filter/FilterFilter.html) that explains how `filter` interprets its argument. I.e. in

```dart
  v | filter:x
```

the argument `x` can be a

- `String`, `bool` and `num`:  Only items in the `List` that
  directly match this expression, items that are Maps with any
  value matching this item and items that are Lists containing a
  matching items are returned.
- `Map`:  This defines a pattern map.  Filters specific
  properties on objects contained in the input List.  For example
  `{name:"M", phone:"1"}` predicate will return a list of items
  which have property `name` containing "M" and property `phone`
  containing "1".  A special property name, `$`, can be used
  (as in `{$: "text"}`) to accept a match against any property of the object.
  That's equivalent to the simple substring match with a `String` as
  described above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'filter:query'. I guess it is the filter `filter`.

`filter` seems to convert the items in the collection to string and compares them with the search text.
If the `toString()` doesn't contain the field you want to compare it won't match.

A custom filter is probably the best option.
Example:
[angular.dart.tutorial / Chapter_07 / lib / filter / category_filter.dart](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart.tutorial/tree/master/Chapter_07/lib/filter)